# Don't Starve Will Crash Seconds After Launching

Tags: technical-issues, dont-starve

So every time I launch don't starve alone it crashes a couple of seconds after it fully boots up.

I was able to play on it the very first time I launched it and played for 53 mins before getting off. Now whenever I launch it, the aforementioned problem happens.

What I've tried:

- Reinstalling it but that didn't change anything.
- Running it as an administrator,
- Turning off fullscreen optimization. When I launch it, it wont respond and show a black screen for a couple of seconds, then it will show the main menu for a few seconds, even letting me click on buttons, then after a seemingly constant amount of time, it crashes.
- Verifying/fixing it through the launcher which didn't fix it.
- Checked to see if its blocked on my firewall but it isn't even listed on my firewall.

I checked the log and the last message it shows is

> CURL ERROR: couldn't connect to host at s3.amazonaws.com:443

This is the GOG version of the game. I have no mods installed. I do have Reign of Giants.

Comment: Any error codes or you are simply suddenly back on the desktop?

Comment: no error codes. The game just closes

Comment: I dont know if its the same in Dont starve normal (or you are on dont starve together) But can you find this file? https://support.klei.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029881191-Logs-and-Useful-Information-for-Bug-Reports-for-Don-t-Starve-Together ? The Documents\Klei\DoNotStarveTogether\client_log.txt part. I have no clue how its setup, but usually you will have a bunch on time stamps and then an error. Can you get us the last few? (There might be a bunch that happened on the same time, if so, take them all)

Comment: Yes i was able to find it

Comment: Wait nevermind didnt finish reading your comment. I found the diagdx.exe but now I see you meant the txt log

Comment: Ok i found the log and these error messages:

Comment: [00:00:10]: CURL ERROR: couldn't connect to host at ds.metrics.klei.com:443
[00:00:11]: QueryServerComplete no callback
[00:00:12]: HttpClientWriteCallback (0x04C8FDAC, 1, 2048, 0x05E2F6F8)
[00:00:12]: HttpClientWriteCallback READ 2048 (2048 total)
[00:00:14]: CURL ERROR: couldn't connect to host at s3.amazonaws.com:443

Comment: It seems to be trying to load to external ressources and is blocked. Maybe its your firewall? Can you play if you are not connected to the internet at all?

Comment: i cant run it internet or no internet

Comment: I dont know much about dont starve so idk why. But i would guess those calls are to check possible multiplayer servers if its a multiplayer only game. Do you have an antivirus or firewall?